# Azure Co-Located-Cache max item size for session state

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-caching

I have undestood that the maximum serialized size of an item in the Co Located Azure Shared Cache (preview) is 8mb.
I am currently using the Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider to store my session state in the cache.

My question is if the session (all session key/values) is serialized as one item or is it each key by it self that can not exceed 8MB?

So if i have 10 keys with 1 mb of data each is it exceding the 8MB limit?

I know that you arent suppose to store that large objects in session (and I don´t 99% of the time) its just to know how some edge cases will behave in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, what you say is correct.  I've used the Microsoft report viewer control which puts a large amount of data into session with a guid key each time you run a new report and if I don't clean out these session keys I see this error.

Comment: I also tried it out and got an error even though each sesssion item is small.

Error Message: Size of message to be sent is 12026791 bytes which is larger than the maximum message size 8388608 specified in configuration.

Stack Trace: at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.VelocityWireProtocol.GetWritePacketBuffer(VelocityPacket packet, IBufferManager bufferManager, Boolean ignoreSizeLimit, IList`1& allocationType)
 at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientChannel.Send(EndpointID endpoint, IVelocityRequestPacket packet)